# Как спроектировать таблицы?

Tags: база-данных

Пытаюсь спроектировать базу по теме рыбалка. Делаю таблицу "Журнал уловов" в которую хочу записывать на какой тип удилища поймана рыба (спининг, донка, поплавок, нахлыст) и приманка (червь, тесто, воблер, силикон) на которую была поймана рыба. И вот проблема в том, что у поплавочного и донного удилища приманки могут быть одинаковые, а у спиннинга и нахлыста они уже другие. Причем мне бы хотелось записывать, если рыба поймана на спининг, какой именно воблер был использован (какой именно фирмы, возможно его размер(большой, средний, маленький).

Answer (score 1):

Наименования написал в транслите, но вы их можете переименовать как вам угодно.

таблица 1) Удилища (id_udilishe - автоинкремент)

```
id_udilishe, name_udilishe
```

таблица 2) Приманка (id_primanka - автоинкремент)

```
 id_primanka, name_primanka
```

таблица 3) Орудие ловли (перове id просто автоинкремент, а 2е и 3е - для этой таблицы берем id из первых двух)

```
 id_orudia, id_udilishe, id_primanka
```

таблица 4) Производитель удилищ (id_brand - автоинкремент, id_udilishe - из таблицы удилиш)

```
id_brand, id_udilishe
```

таблица 5) Размер удилищ (id_razmer - автоинкремент, id_udilishe - из таблицы удилиш)

```
 id_razmer, id_udilishe
```

таблица 6) Результат ловли (id_result - автоинкремент, id_orudia,  id_brand, id_razmer - из соотвествующих таблиц)
id_result, id_orudia,  id_brand, id_razmer

Таблицы 1-5 вы заполняете сами, таблицу № 6 заполняют пользователи сайта.

Comment: Вы не совсем меня поняли. Возьмем пример попроще, интернет-магазин. У магазина есть товары. Товары относятся к каким то каталогам. У магазина есть таблица соответствия, "товар - каталог". Но у каждого каталога товаров есть свои отдельные характеристики, то есть у каталога пылесосы - это мощность, у каталога телевизор - диагональ. Вот меня интересует, как связать товар с его характеристиками.